# How does CodeIgniter send information from a Model to a View with the Controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I call a controller and it calls the model, model returns information from my database assigned to something in the controller.

But how does it "send" it to the view for rendering?  How for example, when I send $data array to my_view.php.  how does it get to that page so that, I am guessing, I can do things like use extract to get my individual variables.

I'm really asking at the php level, how would you send that data (so I can learn).  How does that view know what I sent it?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should read [the code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L413)?

Comment: Yes, it basically extract()'s each key of the data object/array you pass to the view, in the context of the included file.  In newer versions of CI, those values are persistent to all subsequent views, and you can grab a particular "variable" with $this->load->get_var('variable name')

Answer (score 4):

You have to "send" that $data array to the view as the second parameter when you load it.

```
$data['user'] = array(
    'name'   => 'Tom Jones',
    'gender' => 'male'
);

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

Then, the contents of the array are accessed within the view by their corresponding key values

```
<?php echo $user['name']; ?>
```

Checkout out the docs for more details: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern of all php views is this:

```
function render_view($__filename, $__data) {
    extract($__data);
    include $__filename;
}
```

This is *basically* how CodeIgniter does it, but it uses a loader to find the view filename and includes output buffering options.